# Paypal - Return URL array for $_GET

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I am trying to create a php/mysql system where after a buyer buys multiple products from a single cart using paypal, the return URL will include an array of item id's. From there I can use the ids on the return page to delete the items from the system. The sql table that holds all shopping cart data would be called userCarts. Every time a user accesses it, it will first check to see if items are still available then run this:

```
$DB //db info here
$username =  $_SESSION['userlogin'];
$query = SELECT itemID FROM userCarts WHERE user=$username;
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$items = $result->fetch_array(DB_NUM);
$url = 'http://mysite/return.php?';
$url .= 'items[]=' . implode('&amp;items[]=', array_map('urlencode', $items));
```

That way I can generate a valid return Url in Paypal code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php $url ?>">
```

And on Return.php I can use $_GET['items'] to then delete from the available items table.

Right now this is conceptual and I am unable to test using paypal sandbox. I would like to know if the ladder is feasible or if there is a better way to go about it.

Comment: Not sure why you are using `items[]=` in your url. Please explain.

Comment: items[] is for the $_GET in the return.php, so that I can simply call  $_GET['items']. This returns an array. I was under the assumption that I had to add [] so that it understands it is an array, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, your code should look more like:

```
$username =  $_SESSION['userlogin'];
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT itemID FROM userCarts WHERE user=$username");
$url = 'http://mysite/return.php';
if($result->num_rows > 0){
  $url .= '?';
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    foreach($row as $i => $v){
      $url .= "&$i=$v";
    }
  }
}
$url = rawurlencode($url);
$result->free(); $mysqli->close();
```

?????

Comment: I agree with your edit, since I had not included the possibility of 0 rows.